# Generate a report from a wizard in OpenERP 7

Tags: report, odoo, openoffice.org

I am learning how to generates reports in OpenERP and specifically I am trying to be able to generate a report from a `wizard` but I am not able to find much documentation about it.

I am already able to generate a wizard and populate it with the fields I need.For it I created a `sales_wizard` class and an xml file with the structure of the wizard.

my `sales_wizard.py` is inside a `wizard` folder in my custom module and looks similar to this

```
class sales_wizard(osv.osv_memory):

    _name = 'sim.sales.wizard'
    print "Wizard IN"
    _rec_name = 'building'
    _columns = {
                'building':fields.many2one('sim.buildings','building',required=True,ondelete='cascade'),
                'period':fields.many2one('sim.periods','Period',required=True,ondelete='cascade')
                }
```

What I am lacking is the knowledge to understand how to connect the wizard with the creation of a report and how to pass the variables that are input in the wizard, in this case the `building` and the `period`

Any orientation,tip,link to the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find many example of print report from wizard in openerp.
Lets check in product module  product_pricelist report & wizard.

In wizard when you open there is a button print, in print button in py side define code for send data to report

```
def print_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        """
        To get the date and print the report
        @return : return report
        """
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        datas = {'ids': context.get('active_ids', [])}
        res = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['price_list','qty1', 'qty2','qty3','qty4','qty5'], context=context)
        res = res and res[0] or {}
        res['price_list'] = res['price_list'][0]
        datas['form'] = res
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
            'report_name': 'product.pricelist',
            'datas': datas,
       }
```

and in .rml file file define a para like  `<para style="terp_default_Centre_8">[[ get_pricelist(data['form']['price_list']) ]]</para>`

get_pricelist a function define in report file , where data['form']['price_list'] is a argument passed from wizard which used in function get_pricelist

Hope this will help